# Should I start system restore?

Tags: windows, virus, restore

Okay, I have installed a program that gave me many, many PC viruses that can't be deleted, so should I run System Restore?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should run System Restore and restore Windows back to a restore point far back enough in the past to remove the malware. A lot of the instructions on the internet for how to remove a virus from your computer called a.mean.virus.name or whatever other name it is are garbage and will only make matters worse.

Comment: I did all this but I still have some smaller viruses which I think will be easy to remove.

Comment: Superuser users often recommend the answers to this question about how to get rid of nasty viruses and other malware: [How can I remove malicious spyware, malware, adware, viruses, trojans or rootkits from my PC?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-can-i-remove-malicious-spyware-malware-adware-viruses-trojans-or-rootkit).